# Start/Stop Receiver manually and pass parameters to receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

My project is simple. It has an `activity` and a `broadcast receiver`. From within my app I want to be able to **send sms** and to **receive sms**. This works great.

But now I want to pass some data from the view to the receiver. Imagine a simple `checkbox`, I want to pass its value to the `receiver`.

So this is the basic life cycle of my app:

1. Start app
2. Press Send SMS
3. Receiver is started with params and sms is send
4. Receiver gets an sms and stops.

Receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

[Activity:](http://dpaste.com/867749/)
 
[Receiver:](http://dpaste.com/867753/)

I tried to pass a value, but it seems to be ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: if you have any issue in using Custom Intent Broadcasting then see [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/) tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cann't just start and stop a `BroadcastReceiver` at any time you want. `BroadcastReceiver` is only alive while `onReceive()` is executing.
2. To send a broadcast you should use `sendBroadcast(this.service)` instead of `startService(this.service);`
3. Once you change it to `sendBroadcast(this.service)` you will receive **TWO** broadcasts (first from your `sendBroadcast()` and second from `SmsManager`). This is definitely not what you want because in the first case you will be able to get your `checked` param but not `SmsMessage` and vice versa in the second case.
4. You can just store this `checked` param in the `SharedPreferences` and then retrieve it on `onReceive()`

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom Intent Broadcasting  to Achieve Current flow . make changes in your code as:

**STEP 1 :**

register an Custom Intent with `SMS_RECEIVED` in Manifest as :

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
       <action android:name="xx.xxx.xxx.intent.action.SMS_STATUS_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

**STEP 2 :**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public static final String STATUS_INTENT = 
                  "xx.xxx.xxx.intent.action.SMS_STATUS_ACTION";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg1.getAction().equals(SmsReceiver.STATUS_INTENT)) {

                    // get value here sended from Activity 
             }
            else{
                    // Check for SMS_RECEIVED Action here
              }
    }

}
```

**STEP 3 :**

send value from your Activity as using `sendBroadcast` :

```
public static final String STATUS_INTENT = 
                         "xx.xxx.xxx.intent.action.SMS_STATUS_ACTION";
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int checked = 0;

        if(this.param.isChecked()){
            checked = 1;
        }
        // put value here
        Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putInt("param", checked);
            intent.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
     }
```

Comment: If I understood well artworkad wants to get `checked` param when `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` is broabcasted but not to send custom broadcast

Comment: vmironov is right. I tried the above code and it works, however I am not able to access the checkbox value when sms is received, just on the custom event.

Comment: however, +1 one for the comprehensive information on custom intents